# Methods to see if user is online, performance

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm developing a user-system where I want to see if a user is online. I've considered making an extra column in my users table, with `last_action`. This would update **every time** a user looks at a page.

This would obviously require the MySQL database to update the user row every time a page is loaded. Would this be an optimal way of doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by "online"?  How do users interract with your application?  My guess is that it might be over stateless HTTP with some server-side scripting language like PHP, but there's nothing in your question to confirm those assumptions.

Comment: It's a user system written in PHP using the CodeIgniter framework

Comment: And users are connecting over HTTP?  Whilst this is likely given your use of PHP and CodeIgniter, it's not mandatory; but the information is essential to answering your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve that using cookies.
At your database, you already seem to have a `Time` (or similar) field. Just do the same for a cookie. Then, you can compare the cookie's time to the current one, and if the difference is large enough (e.g. 5, 10 minutes) you can edit it in the database as well.